# How to assume preClass object

Tags: c#, static

Is it possible to have the IDE or code understand and assume a method is apart of a class?

I have 2 classes.

Class A is my standard class.
Class B is my class I want class A to have access to.

I want Class A to be able to see and call static functions inside of class B.

However, I do not want to have to say 
ClassB.FunctionA();

I just want to say FunctionA();
[image]
Is that possible? Am i reading to far into this?

In the photo above, you can see my namespace being "NQAP.Selenium"
This namespace has a static class called "WindowActions"
This static class has functions such as SendKeys and Click.

I just want to say "SendKeys" and not have to say "WindowActions.SendKeys"
See new image.  I cannot use "using static"

[image]

Comment: I think what you are talking about is inheritance, but I'm not sure. The only way to do that in C# is to either use inheritance, or to use the `using` alias with static types. In your example, you would type `using static WindowActions;` at the top of your file.

Comment: i tried the "using" alias, but it doesn't show up in the intellisense.

Comment: Screen captures of code are more work for everyone.

Comment: Thank you Joel, I'll keep that in mind on my next question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I undertstand `using ststic` is what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static

Comment: updated question with new photo showing its not possible.  I should mention that NQAP. is in a different project.

Comment: @A.Mills You are typing it wrong, it is `WindowActions` not `WindowsActions`

Comment: Thank you, sorry its been a long week haha

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net has been able to do this since the beginning.

C# version 6 and later can do this with the `using static` alias.

```
using static NQAP.Selenium.WindowActions;

//...

SendKeys(...);
```

C# prior to version 6 could use an alias for the type name to cut down on re-typing the long name:

```
using WA = NQAP.Selenium.WindowActions;

//...


WA.SendKeys(...);
```

Comment: And I could have posted this a lot faster if I could have copy/pasted from the question rather than re-typing. Screen shots of code are not your friend.